# How to expose an entity reference field as a filter on a custom entity in Views?

Tags: views, 8

I have a field on a custom entity that is an entity reference to a node. However when I select this field as a filter and expose it, it just acts like a numeric field instead of a reference field (only option is less than, greater than, equal to... etc).

How can I make this field act properly? I just want a drop down of options (only 32 nodes ever) to make filtering easy.

Comment: Last time I had the same issue there was nothing in core, the closest thing in contrib is this alpha module I think: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_exposed_filters. The form alter and manually loading the entities as options is a pretty good solution too

Comment: I also just came across this: https://www.drupal.org/project/verf

Comment: Good find, just checked the code for the views filter and it's a lot better in verf

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many solutions but I resolved the same problem in the hook
hook_form_alter()
altering the form element type from textfield to select and populate the #option attribute:

```
  $options = _getOptions();
  $form['your_field'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
  ];
```

Other solutions are appreciated.